# Setting Meta-Properties to Vertex properties with Gremlin

Tags: graph, gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop

I'm very new to TinkerPop and graphdb's in general so forgive me if this is a silly question.

I have the following in graph as a property of one of my vertices:

```
"BOM": [
        {
          "id": "5228f5ea-6a26-49c7-ac22-d530783ff5f9",
          "value": "V_5842_Snack Pack Box"
        }
      ]
```

My issue is that I need to add `meta` properties so that it looks like this instead:

```
      "BOM": [
        {
          "id": "c458f282-edf4-4539-adbc-eb2fa20a969b",
          "value": "V_5842_Snack Pack Box",
          "properties": {
            "ItemNumber": "5842",
            "LineNumber": "1",
            "Quantity": "1",
            "CreatedBy": "?",
            "CreatedOn": "2021-08-18T11:48:16Z",
            "ModifiedOn": "2021-08-19T19:19:08Z",
            "ModifiedBy": "JAttar"
          }
        }
      ]
```

Does anyone know how I go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ended up figuring this out by first finding a `BOM` with a specific value and then making use of the `.property()` method.

```
g.V().has('id', 'fakeID').properties('BOM').hasValue('V_5842_Snack Pack Box').
  property('ItemNumber', '5842').
  property('LineNumber', '1'.
  property('Quantity', '1') ....
```